# How to pass AJAX arguments to the extbase action?

Tags: ajax, action, typo3, param, extbase

Now that I managed to get values from the database, I want to specify more what I want to be passed.

From a select box that reacts to the event function below, I want to read out a value (uid of a record) and pass it to my ajaxAction:

```
    
    var uid;
    $('#mySelectBox').change(function() {
        arguments = $(this).attr('value');
        var uri = '<f:uri.action arguments="{uid: '+uid+'}" action="ajax" controller="Mycontroller1" pageType="89657201" />';

        jQuery.getJSON(uri, function(result) {
            // do something
        });
    });
```

I tried it with arguments, no idea if that is the right way. Additionally, as Marcus Biesioroff suggested, I should save my JS into a separate file, but then I would have to write the uri on my own instead of the Fluid way, right?

My ajaxAction looks like this:

```
    
        public function ajaxAction($uid) {
            $dataFromRepo = $this->myRepository->findByUid($uid);

            $resultArray = array(
                "field1" => $dataFromRepo->getField1(),
                "field2" => $dataFromRepo->getField2(),
                "field3" => $dataFromRepo->getField3(),
                "field4" => $dataFromRepo->getField4(),
            );
            return json_encode($resultArray);
        }
```

I'm sure that the uid is not passed correctly, everything else works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some mistakes:

- You can't break vievhelper's syntax with JS even if it's placed in view, you need to pass **full** path of the action from `<f:uri.action />`
- you cannot place this JS in view, because it contains curly brackets there's [other description of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10214274/1066240)
- you need to call ajax function  from external file and pass to it action's link and uid separately, and then add the

in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var actionsPathFromViewHelperSetInTheView 
        = '<f:uri.action action="ajax" controller="Mycontroller1" pageType="89657201" />';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/ext/Public/yourExternal.js"></script>


<!-- of course this field may/should be created with Fluid's viewhelper -->
<select id="mySelectBox" onchange="performAjaxCall(this)">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

in the `yourExternal.js` (of course you need to change `tx_yourextkey_yourplugin` prefix to your own)

```
function performAjaxCall(selectFieldObj) {
    $.ajax({
        url: actionsPathFromViewHelperSetInTheView,
        data:{
            "tx_yourextkey_yourplugin[uid]":selectFieldObj.value
        },
        success:function (data) {
            // do something with your json
            alert('Load was performed.');
        }
    });
}
```

in your controller:

```
public function ajaxAction() {

    // try to always validate the incoming arguments
    if (!$this->request->hasArgument('uid') || intval($this->request->getArgument('uid')) == 0) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
        return json_encode(array('error'=> 'Bad request'));
    }

    $uid = intval($this->request->getArgument('uid'));

    $dataFromRepo = $this->myRepository->findByUid($uid);
    if ($dataFromRepo == null) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not found');
        return json_encode(
           array('error'=> 'Not found or you have no access or something else... happens...')
        );
    }
    $resultArray = array(
        "field1" => $dataFromRepo->getField1(),
        // etc...
    );

    return json_encode($resultArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was just about to answer it myself (can't, not enough rep.), which is basically the same, but yours makes sure to handle errors etc.

Comment: I've found a solution I'm happy with.

I write the uri like this (withthe uid at the end):
<pre>

    <code>
     var uid = $(this).attr('value');
     var uri = 'index.php?tx_myextension_myplugin[action]=ajax&tx_myextension_myplugin[controller]=Mycontroller1&type=89657201&tx_myextension_myplugin[uid]='+uid;
    </code>

</pre>

In my ajaxAction I add:
<pre>

    <code>
    $showUid = mysql_real_escape_string($this->request->getArgument('uid'));
    </code>

</pre>

This is gonna contain the uid, so I can use it for further steps, yay :)

Comment: Such advice, always check if `$this->request->hasArgument('some')` before you'll try to `$this->request->getArgument('some')` also check if data from repo isn't null to prevent exceptions

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll keep it in mind. I learned a lot the last two days :)